# Geofirestore documentation

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, geofirestore

I am attempting to use Geofirestore with my VueJs/Firestore application but can't seem to find the complete set of documentaton of the GeoFirestore library. I can only find the documentation listed at geofirestore.com and https://github.com/geofirestore/geofirestore-js but this is very limited. I have been able to successfully add location data to my FireStore collection and query it user the "Near" method but I need more information about the return results on the GeoQuerySnapshot. For instance, I receive a distance attribute in my return object but I don't whether that is in miles or kilometers or what? There has to be more documentation than what is listed on these two sites...no? Appreciate the help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So pretty much the documentation is the Firestore documentation minus the fact that there is the added `near` function.

So for example, the [`GeoQuerySnapshot`](https://geofirestore.com/classes/_geoquerysnapshot_.geoquerysnapshot.html#docs) has three accessors (`docs`, `empty` and `size`) and two methods (`docChanges()`, and `forEach()`), which is very similar to a [Firestore QuerySnapshot](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.QuerySnapshot).

If you do access the docs, which is an array of [`QueryDocumentSnapshot`](https://geofirestore.com/interfaces/_geofirestoretypes_.geofirestoretypes.querydocumentsnapshot.html) which has 4 properties:

- The `data` of the document (your data).
- The `distance` from your center (null if it's a query made without a location).
- `exists` to let you know if the doc exists or not (this can change, but most likely will always be true).
- And finally the `id` of the doc

As I mentioned, the structure and what you get is almost identical to how Firestore works (except Firestore doesn't provide `distance`).

Comment: Thank you for your response. I have a few of specific questions that hopefully you can answer. 1. When I receive results from the query is the distance in kilometers? 2. Is the radius on the query in kilometers? 3. Is it frowned upon to store my document data within the GeoFirestore "d" object? Initially I just used it as an index but found that I would then need to create a promise.all to query for the actual documents. If I store in the "d" object I don't have to do that. Thanks ahead of time.

Comment: So the answer to question 1 and 2 is yes, its all in kilometers. As to question 3, geofirestore automatically puts docs into the `d` field so you dont need to worry about that (unless im misunderstanding you)

Comment: HI @MichaelSolati, Thank you very much for making GeoFirestore it's fantastic. I've a question though, is there any difference between using firestore's delete document method and geofirestore's delete method? is it ok to delete using firestores delete? for example I'm assuming that the difference between the document add method from geofirestore and firestore, is that geofirestore adds the d,l,g fields as well as doing many other things. Thanks Again

Comment: @AndrewIrwin you can use the regular firestore delete method, you don't need geofirestore to do any special cooking for you.

Comment: @MichaelSolati https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72263080/the-best-way-to-query-by-location-in-firestore