# Apply Firestore filtering for specific case

Tags: java, android, google-cloud-firestore, firebaseui

I have collection `trips` with document inside it with fields: `latitude` and `longitude` of some place. I need to retrieve the trips from `Firestore` and take those trips, the distance from its start point to a given point is less than 50m. We can’t apply basic filtering here like `GreaterThan` or `LessThan` methods. I guess we need to filter it on client.

If I used a classic Adapter, I would just send a `ArrayList<MyTrip>` object into adapter and doing filtering here would be easy. But I want to use `FirebasePagingAdapter` in order to paginate data. Here we send `FirestorePagingOptions.Builder<>` object to adapter. And we can set data to it only with `setQuery()` method that takes Query object. My question is how to filter Query object in that case?

```
query = firebaseFirestore.collectionGroup("trips");

config = new PagedList.Config.Builder()
                .setInitialLoadSizeHint(10)
                .setPageSize(5)
                .build();

options = new FirestorePagingOptions.Builder<MyTrip>()
                .setQuery(query, config, MyTrip.class)
                .build();

adapter = new FirestorePagingAdapter<MyPost, PostViewHolder>(options){...}
```

Comment: For filtering on distance, did you see https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/solutions/geoqueries?

Comment: no, I didn’t
thx for the answer, I will check it

Comment: well probably the problem will remain the same, because in result we will get List<DocumentSnapshot>, but not the Query object that I need to put into my case

Comment: To fulfil a geoquery requires multiple queries (see my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72263080/the-best-way-to-query-by-location-in-firestore/72264786#72264786) for some more info on why this is), so there's no way to use that with the adapters in FirebaseUI.

Comment: so, no solution for my particular case?