# Cannot have inequality filters on multiple properties

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am storing a few places by longitude and latitude on a firestore cloud server.

Now, when the user open a map, I would like to load the item around him, so inside the map bounds.

I make a request to my server

```
  const ne = map.getBounds()?.getNorthEast();
  const sw = map.getBounds()?.getSouthWest();

  const { data: places } = useApiRequest<Place[]>({
    operation: () =>
      axios.get(
        `/places?${`minLatitude=${sw?.lat()}&maxLatitude=${ne?.lat()}&minLongitude=${sw?.lng()}&maxLongitude=${ne?.lng()}`}`
      ),
  });
```

And try to query in my BE

```
    const querySnapshot = await collectionRef
      .where('latitude', '>=', minLatitude)
      .where('latitude', '<=', maxLatitude)
      .where('longitude', '>=', minLongitude)
      .where('longitude', '<=', maxLongitude)
      .get();
```

This will cause

> INVALID_ARGUMENT: Cannot have inequality filters on multiple properties: [latitude, longitude]

Which I now found that is a limitation of firestore (wow)...

My question is, what should I now do ?

Those kinds of filtered query are pretty common for any website with a minimum of filtering.
I am pretty surprised by the limitation so I guess there are some workaround or way to do what I need. Am I supposed to query ALL documents and filter on the server ?

Comment: This one one of the most-asked questions about Firestore, and has been discussed thoroughly in other questions, in addition to the [documentation on limitations](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#query_limitations).  If you need range filters on multiple fields, then you're going to have to switch to another database and give up the massive scalability guarantees that Firestore offers (that other database don't).

Answer (score 2):

Firestore currently only supports inequality conditions on a single field. There is no generic workaround for this.

For this specific use-case, there is a common workaround though, based on pre-calculating geohashes and then filtering on those. For more on this, see the documentation on [geoqueries](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/solutions/geoqueries).

Also see:

- [Firestore multiple range query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50658651/firestore-multiple-range-query/50658718#50658718)
- [How do I Query Firebase Firestore for a field of type Geopoint in Flutter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71279853/how-do-i-query-firebase-firestore-for-a-field-of-type-geopoint-in-flutter/71279969#71279969)
- [How to run a geo "nearby" query with firestore?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46630507/how-to-run-a-geo-nearby-query-with-firestore/66354370#66354370)
- [The best way to query by location in firestore](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72263080/the-best-way-to-query-by-location-in-firestore/72264786#72264786)